# Javascript ES6+ named default export syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is this valid export syntax?

```
export default debug = {
    myfunction: myFunction
};
```

Comment: Yes it is valid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As debug is not defined when you assign your export object to it, and modules [are run in strict mode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), no. This is not valid. If you feel you must export a named object, you must declare it first.

```
let debug;
export default debug = {};
```

Note that you cannot declare the variable and export it in the same line.

```
export default const debug = {}; // invalid
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

> Note that it is not possible to use var, let or const with export default.

Comment: Thank you. I was asking because I was building this with jspm and it did complain about "debug" not being defined. I ended up doing what you posted.

Comment: *"Valid in that it will run? Yes."* Not quite. Since modules are in strict mode and you cannot assign to undeclared variables in strict mode, this will throw a runtime error.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I'm so used to working with transpilers I completely forgot about that. Answer fixed.

Comment: Thanks to you both for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

Default export syntax is correct.

But one catch here the variable 'debug' needs to be decalred.

You do something like below:

```
export default {
    myfunction: myFunction
}
```

or

```
const deb = {
    myfunction: myFunction
}
export default deb;
```